# Google cloud platform support plan from API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been looking for a programmatic way to get the support plan for each sub-account we have from GCP. I've looked under Google::Cloud::ResourceManager (Ruby SDK) but it only gives me administrative information (like labels, name, id, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Google support there is no API or programmatic way to get the support level for projects (and by definition - sub-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider taking advantage of the useful "gcloud compute project-info" command, documented on the similarly-titled [page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/project-info/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Google Cloud SDK 220.0.0 (bq 2.0.34, core 2018.10.08, gsutil 4.34) and output of the *describe* which I'm guessing is what you meant is (as the documentation said) only metadata on, well, compute for the project. Information like "commonInstanceMetadata", quotas, name, id, kind, etc. There is no actual information on the project level regarding support.

Comment: By the way - if you meant "gcloud projects describe [PROJECT_ID]" it also doesn't show the project support plan

Comment: You seem to want to retrieve the name of the project programmatically, as well as its ID. In this case, what would you be searching for, to retrieve the name of a project as a result? 
For your 2000 project, it would have been easier to store metadata of interest at the moment of creation for each and every project, and devise a way to retrieve data items of interest by means of a custom search.

Comment: That is not what my question says. I want to retrieve the project *support plan*. We are under the legacy support programs that are enabled to only some projects out of existing 2000+ projects, because there is no correlation between project and support plan I can't think of any way to see which support plan is enabled for each project, bronze, gold or silver.

Comment: Also, it would have made sense if the question was on future infrastructure,and nor existing one. I'm using labels on every level of the GCP, and setting a label with a support plan enabled would have made sense if I were managing the infrastructure from the start, but this is what I got today :)